# Use isdigit in C programming

Tags: c, windows

I would need some help regarding how to use `isdigit()` in this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
   int usr_option;
   do
   {
      printf("\t\t\t************************MENU***********************\n");
      printf("\t\t\t***  1. Enter Code\t\t\t\t***\n");
      printf("\t\t\t***  2. Encrypt code and verify if correct\t***\n");
      printf("\t\t\t***  3. Decrypt code\t\t\t\t***\n");
      printf("\t\t\t***  4. Display number of times code was enter\t***\n");
      printf("\t\t\t***\t\t(i) Successfully\t\t***\n");
      printf("\t\t\t***\t\t(i) Unsuccessfully\t\t***\n");
      printf("\t\t\t***  5. Exit Program\t\t\t\t***\n");
      printf("\t\t\t***************************************************\n");
      printf("\nPlease enter your option from the menu: ");
      scanf("%d", &usr_option); 
      if (isdigit(usr_option))
      {
          //Inside here is my switch case e.g switch(usr_option){/*code*/}
      }
      else
      {
        printf("Need to enter a digit\n");
      }          
    }//end do while 
    while(usr_option != 5);
    return 0;
 }
```

How can I implement this code to not go into an infinite loop?
I've tried different ways but it seems like it doesn't want to work. I use the compilers CodeBlocks and Sublime Text 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have read a number via `scanf("%d", &usr_option);` Then you don't need to use `is_digit()` You can just use `if` or `switch` e.g.

```
switch(usr_option)
{
    case 1: enter_code(); break;
    case 2: encrypt(); break;
```

You only need `is_digit` if you are checking that characters in a string are digits or not.

i.e. `'1' != 1`

Comment: You should still check the return value of `scanf`. If it is different from `1`, `usr_option` holds random data.